# Is there a javascript bind like function in java

Tags: java, javascript

I'm newbea to java and i want to know is there anything similar functionality as javascript bind in java.

ex :

```
function x(bindedArg, arg1, arg2){

}

x.bind(this, 'bindedArg');

x('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Update:

A good example would be in event's callback function.

What if i need an object / argument available in the actual event callBack context, that was previously available at the time of setting a callback to an event.

Comment: `this` in Java is not the same concept as `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: You will get better answers if you have an example of where you need this in Java. Normally, you don't pass functions around in Java, and there is usually another way to achieve it (like the Listener pattern or anonymous inner classes implementing some interface).

Comment: In java script bind allows set the value of "this" to an specific object, reuse methods and curry a function. But In Java those are different concepts.

Comment: @Thilo i hope the update gives a picture of it.

Comment: @Beast: Not really. This usually does not happen in Java. You don't pass around callbacks, you pass around objects that have a method to handle the callback. So in a way, you pass around both the callback and the `this`.

Comment: @Thilo that's what i wanted, how to pass an object when you are not the one who will be calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you don't pass around "callbacks".

You pass around object instances that implement some callback interface.

Instead of calling a callback, the framework code can then invoke a method (defined in the interface) on the object.

For example

```
 interface ClickHandler{
      void handleClick(Event event);
 }


// and then

 final String someStateIHave = "hello";

 myButton.setClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
      void handleClick(Event event){
         System.out.println(someStateIHave);
      }
 }
```

As you can see, there is an object instance of ClickHandler (anonymous inner class in this case, but does not have to be). The UI framework can then call the `handleClick` method on this object. And the object has access to whatever other objects it needs.

This pattern (anonymous implementation of single method interface) is so frequent that Java 8 has a special, concise syntax for it.

Comment: But @Thilo, we are maintaining a String outside the scope of the clickHandler, what i wanted is like
`myButton.setClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
 void handleClick(String someStateIHave, Event event){
  
 }
})`

The someStateIHave should be available as an argument to the handleClick function

Comment: You can add more parameters to the interface of the method. But then I would not call it "state".

Comment: Suppose i want `String 'SomeStr'`, even if we add in the parameter in interface, that'll not be equal to `'SomeStr'` right ?
@Thilo hope i'm not confusing:)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  However, one can write a little Adapter or Decorator class.  For example, if there is an interface you must match

```
interface Callback {
    public callback(Error err, Data data);
}
```

and you want to call your function x, you'd create an anonymous class

```
new Callback() {
   public callback(Error err, Data data) {
      x(bindedArg, err, data);
   }
}
```

Or, if you plan to do this a lot, create a real class and pass bindedArg to the constructor, e.g.

```
class MyCallback implements Callback {
   final Object bindedArg;

   public MyCallback(Object o) { 
      bindedArg = o;
   }

   public callback(Error err, Data data) {
      x(bindedArg, err, data);
   }

}
```

Not as easy as in JavaScript but the same idea, a function to wrap another function.

Comment: That was the exact idea my brain came up with, 
we can take the data from constructor parameters and then call the function we want with the parameter added.
but little different way though,
what i thought was like taking the data in interface constructor parameter and then accessing in callback function definition area.

Comment: The interface "constructor" can't take any parameters - you need the extra effort to define a class for that.  However, variables that happen to be in scope can, with some caveats, be used inside the anonymous class / "closure-like-thing".  If you are going to do the same thing _a lot_ I think the effort to make a class is worth it.  Else use the anonymous class.  YMMV.